# What is the purpose of the "databases" line here in this Firestore security rule?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In the documentation bout recursive wildcards: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards

We have the following:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Matches any document in the cities collection as well as any document
    // in a subcollection.
    match /cities/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if <condition>;
    }
  }
}
```

What is the purpose of the line `match /databases/{database}/documents {`? I thought I could only create one database per project in Firestore. Does this mean I can create database A and database B within the same project? Do I even need this line if I only want to have 1 database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Currently you can indeed only have one Firestore database per project, but that may change in the future. At that point, the `{database}` variable can be used to differentiate between the database instances in your project.

Comment: Ahh ok. So then if I remove this line it won't make a difference? Or do I need to leave it there?

Comment: That line is necessary.